# cannot find symbol while creating 2D array with random numbers

Tags: java, random

I need to create a 2D array using randomly generated numbers. I am going to add more methods to the program, but for now I am just trying to make the table.

Java gives me a cann ot find symbol error when I compile this, but I see nothing wrong with these lines.

Note: for easier reading, I only put one line, as all the lines are exactly the same except for the variable and they get the exact same error.

```
import java.util.Random;


public class third {

public static void main(String[] args) {

  makeTable();

}

public static void makeTable() {

  int rand1, rand2, rand3, rand4, rand5, rand6, rand7, rand8, rand9, rand10, rand11, rand12, rand13, rand14, rand15, rand16, rand17, rand18, rand19, rand20;

  rand1 = generator.nextInt(11);
  ...
  rand20 = generator.nextInt(11);

  int[][] table = {{ rand1,  rand2,  rand3,  rand4},
                   { rand5,  rand6,  rand7,  rand8},
                   { rand9,  rand10, rand11, rand12},
                   { rand13, rand14, rand15, rand16},
                   { rand17, rand18, rand19, rand20}};

  System.out.print(table);
} 
}
```

This is the error (again, took most out, but all are the same).

```
C:\!!VHSJava\third.java:24: error: cannot find symbol
  rand1 = generator.nextInt(11);
          ^
```

Could anyone help?

Comment: Please don't create 20 lines of almost equal code, but use a loop: `int[][] table = new int[1][20]; for (int i = 0; i < table[0].length; i++) {table[0][i] = generator.nextInt(11);}`

Comment: You are using the variable name `generator` but you never defined anything with that name. It looks like you want to generate random numbers, so you should add the line `Random generator = new Random();`. Also, [give this a read.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html)

Answer (score 1):

BTW, you can do it with `for` cycle. And of course create `Random` class instance before.

```
public static void makeTable() {
    Random generator = new Random();
    int[][] table = new int[5][4];
    for(int i = 0; i< 5; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            table[i][j] = generator.nextInt(11);
        }
    }
    System.out.print(table);
}
```

And you can print 2D array on during iteration, adding the following commands:

```
System.out.printf("%2d ", table[i][j]); // calculating  table[i][j]
System.out.println(); // after inside cycle, and remove System.out.print(table); at the end.
```